# MySQL list of types with sum of each type

Tags: mysql, list, sum

I have something like that

```
type   number
-----  ------
apple  2
apple  3
pear   1
pear   1
```

and I need to produce a result:

```
type   number
-----  ------
apple  5
pear   2
```

with single SELECT  used.

I have no problem with one type:
SELECT type, SUM(number)FROM table WHERE type ='apple';

Tried to do that in many ways for whole table but there was an always kind of syntax error.

Comment: `SELECT type, SUM(number) FROM table GROUP BY type;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simple [Group By with aggregation](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) problem. `Group By` on `type` will club all the rows of a particular type into one. You can then use aggregation functions like [`Sum()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) to calculate sum of number values for a particular type.

```
SELECT type, 
       SUM(number) AS number 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY type
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the GROUP BY statement.
Is used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result by one or more columns.

```
SELECT type, SUM(number) as number_sum FROM table GROUP BY type;
```